# Node.js , ExpressJS app.get(.......){.....};

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing the server side app for webpage with node.js , now I want to get a request like this **www.example.com/item/xxxx** . xxxx those are 4digit numbers like (1234). 
With node.js and expressjs we can do sth like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This will send hello world when we request the example.com , but how to get the **www.example.com/item/xxxx** requests ?

Comment: The documentation has a large section on it. Please do some basic research before resorting to Stackoverflow. http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: seanhodges , thank you ! that was the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get(/^\/item\/[0-9]{4}$/, function(req, res) {
  // route handler here
});
```

Comment: and how can I get xxxx from server side code?